# compute distance matrix from list of vectors

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Say I have a list of vectors and I want to generate a distance matrix from it. What is a neat way to do it? Eg, I have a list of 3 vectors:

```
k = [[2, 4, 7], [3, 4, 7], [5,1,3]]
distance = pairwise_distances(v1, v2, metric='cosine', n_jobs=-1)
```

Desired output: A numpy array of cosine-distances of the given vector list.

```
array([[ 1.        ,  0.00638545,  0.28778769],
       [ 0.00638545,  1.        ,  0.21402251],
       [ 0.28778769,  0.21402251,  1.        ]])
```

This is what I have done: Got all the combinations using itertools.combinations. Computed the distances for each pair. Then, it becomes a little messy to actually place the distance measures at the "right" cell (need indices of the original vectors in the list).

```
combs = list(itertools.combinations(k, 2))
print combs
```

Is there a "neater" or "pythonic" way of getting at the final distance matrix?

Comment: Since you have tagged `Scipy` - Did you take a look at [`cdist, pdist, squareform in Scipy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html)?

Comment: Hmmm, squareform looks promising. I am aware of pdist, cdist. Thanks for pointing it out. Let me give it a try.

Comment: Also note that the distance matrix is symmetric and the diagonal is 1. You only need to compute one triangular part.

Comment: I.e. only compute d_ij for i<j, set d_ii = 1 and d_ji = d_ij..

Comment: The diagonal of a *distance* matrix will be 0.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Divakar's suggestion, I was able to get what I wanted. here is snippet for those who are looking for an answer:

```
distance_vectors = [cosine_distance([pair[0]], [pair[1]]) for pair in combs]
print distance_vectors

distance_vectors = [x[0][0] for x in distance_vectors]
print distance_vectors
X = squareform(np.array(distance_vectors))
print X
```

And, yes (thanks to @Warren), the diagonal of a distance matrix is zero.

Comment: `pdist` has a cosine metric. So, you could directly use that and thus avoid the looping at the first step.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can think of is:

```
cdist(k,k,'cosine')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Again, thanks to @Divakar, a more compact way to do it:

```
k = [[2, 4, 7], [3, 4, 7], [5,1,3]]
dm = pdist(np.array(k), 'cosine')
dm = squareform(dm)
print dm
```

Can't get any better!!

Thanks!